# Why is `promise_type::await_transform` greedy?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, c++-coroutine

It looks like `await_transform` in C++20 coroutines is greedy. I mean - if you only add at least one `await_tranform` to your `promise_type`, then it is being applicable for every `co_await` expression, regardless its type matches or not.

See the code:

```cpp
#include <coroutine>
#include <utility>

struct coro
{
    struct promise_type
    {
        std::suspend_never initial_suspend() { return {}; }
        std::suspend_never final_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
        void return_void() {}
        void unhandled_exception() {}
        coro get_return_object() { return {}; }

        std::suspend_never await_transform(int) { return {}; }
    };
};

coro foo()
{
    co_await 1;
    co_await std::suspend_never{};
}

int main() {
    foo();
}
```

I get errors for all 3 compilers (gcc, clang and MSVC) similar errors (this one is from [MSVC](https://godbolt.org/z/6h6qacxPe):

```
example.cpp
<source>(21): error C2664: 'std::suspend_never coro::promise_type::await_transform(int)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::suspend_never' to 'int'
<source>(21): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
<source>(14): note: see declaration of 'coro::promise_type::await_transform'
<source>(21): note: while trying to match the argument list '(std::suspend_never)'
Compiler returned: 2
```

I see in [this C++ standard draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.await) that it is most probably a behavior defined/required by C++ standard:

> Evaluation of an *await-expression* involves the following auxiliary
> types, expressions, and objects:
>
> (3.1) `p` is an lvalue naming the
> promise object ([dcl.fct.def.coroutine]) of the enclosing coroutine
> and `P` is the type of that object.
>
> (3.2) Unless the *await-expression*
> was implicitly produced by a *yield-expression* ([expr.yield]), an
> initial await expression, or a final await expression
> ([dcl.fct.def.coroutine]), a search is performed for the name
> `await_transform` in the scope of `P` ([class.member.lookup]). **If this
> search is performed and finds at least one declaration, then `a` is
> `p.await_transform(cast-expression)`**; otherwise, `a` is the
> `cast-expression`.

So my question is:

1. Am I right - does C++ standard define this greedy behavior?
2. If I am right here, then I see as reasonable to change this behavior: to consider only `await_transform` that matches the `await-expression` type. So, are there any proposals on this area to C++ standard committee?
3. Or maybe it has to be as it is. Then, is there some rationale for this behavior?

Comment: What if you want to ban awaiting certain types?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - well, I can imagine this is to be achieved by deleting `void await_transform(ATypeToBeBanned const&&) = delete;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I right - so C++ standard defines this strange behavior?

You just cited the part of the standard that specifies this.

> are there any proposals on this area to C++ standard committee?

No.

> Then, is there some rationale for this behavior?

The answer is in a different question: what is `await_transform` meant to do?

Normally, `co_await` is a process that involves two objects: the awaitable type and the coroutine that may be suspended/resumed. The idea is to allow the awaitable type to determine when the coroutine is resumed, or even whether it should be suspended right now at all, as well as to manufacture the value when the time comes.

However, the behavior of a coroutine with regard to the outside world is governed by the coroutine machinery. And that is defined through the coroutine's promise. This is the interface the outside world uses to manipulate the coroutine. It also defines what functionality is supported.

Let's say you want to have a coroutine that can be terminated. The future type returned has a cancel function to end execution without bothering with a value. The idea being that at every suspension/resume point, the system will check to see if the coroutine has been canceled and exit without resumption.

But the future can only talk to the *promise*. And the promise doesn't talk to the awaitable.

This is what `await_transform` is for: allowing the promise to instrument any awaitable type. To declare the existence of such a function is to declare that your promise *cannot work* unless it instruments the awaitable, that it specifically needs to do so.

If you want to have certain specific `co_await`s be instrumented by the promise, you can do that by doing `co_await my_instrumented_awaitable(<expr>)` manually as needed. But if you need *all of them* to be instrumented (which can be used for tracing suspend/resume points), if it's not something you pick-and-choose, then you use `await_transform`.

It's also useful for being able to actively shut off specific awaitables, or to only *allow* the use of specific awaitables. You can even conceptualize the interface so that only awaitables with a certain interface are allowed.

It works the way it does because that's the point of the feature. It's not an accident or a mistake; it's what the feature is *for*. If you're using `await_transform`, it is because you either want to instrument *all* awaitables or restrict the awaitables you can await on (or both). And the existing behavior serves those needs.

Your example code seems to be trying to just communicate an arbitrary value to the promise and potentially suspend the coroutine based on what the promise wants to do. The correct spelling for this is `co_yield`, not `co_await`.

Notably, `co_yield` *bypasses* `await_transform`.

Comment: My example, it is very simplified one. My real code is when I want to wait from one coroutine to end of other coroutine. Then - I do `auto s1 = subcoro1(); auto status = co_await s1;` So - I use co_await - I am not yielding something, I am waiting for something.  I use await_transform to build awaitable with current coroutine handle.  On the other hand - I use some other awaitable - e.g. I wait for some message to be dispatched to my coroutine. I find it very "disappointing" that I need to write this funny generic await_transform. To block T - I can `await_transform(T) = delete;` if needed.

Comment: @PiotrNycz: "*So - I use co_await - I am not yielding something, I am waiting for something*" No, you are *polling* for something, not waiting. `co_await` is not for polling; it's for scheduling resumption with the awaitable. If the awaitable cannot schedule resumption, then it's not an awaitable and you're not awaiting on it; you're just polling it. `co_yield` makes far more sense for polling, since it makes it clear that you are *not* transferring control of the coroutine to the non-existent awaitable.

Comment: @PiotrNycz: Basically, `co_await` is not meant to be a generic "wait for any stuff" tool, and trying to use it as such will run into rough edges. It's a tool for continuation-based asynchronous programming. You don't check to see if the thing is ready; the thing will *tell you* when it is ready by resuming your coroutine. And if `co_yield` is not to your liking, you can always `co_await is_ready(status);`, where `is_ready` returns an awaitable that does what you want. It also makes it clear that you're not using continuation-based coding.

Comment: What if I need co_await for two things from inside my coroutine - one awaitable I can just create inside my coroutine directly, the other needs promise_type internals - so I use await_transform. So I'm sorry, but this explanation doesn't convince me to believe that this is the right behavior, it's defined by the standard. But well, it is what it is. Maybe someone (or me) will write a proposal to change this.

Comment: @PiotrNycz: "*one awaitable I can just create inside my coroutine directly, the other needs promise_type internals*" Where does this circumstance appear? What is this coroutine doing where this would come up? Why does that one "need promise_type internals" and the other doesn't? You can theorycraft any particular scenario you like, but that doesn't make it a reasonable use of the feature. `co_await` and its constructs were designed to solve a particular set of problems very elegantly. The farther outside of that domain you get, the less elegant its solutions will be.

Comment: @PiotrNycz: Also, `await_suspend` on the awaitable gets a `coroutine_handle<T>`. So if it needs to talk to the promise, it can always convert the handle to a promise. And `await_suspend` can decide not to halt the coroutine.

Comment: `await_suspend` is not called if `await_ready` says it is not needed to suspend.  When co_await-ing for another coroutine - I can skip "suspend" point when it is already done,. Of course I could check before my I even call `co_await other_coro;` - but I see it more OO to have its coroutine_handle private - so currenlty only available via `await_transform`.  And for me `auto status = co_await other_coro;` is more elegant than `if (!other_coro.handle.done()) status = co_await other_coro; else status = other_coro.handle.promise().status;`

Comment: Anyway - can you add to your response - or add link - to some  use of await_transform that is "reasonable"? I mean the code example. .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253340/discussion-between-nicol-bolas-and-piotrnycz).